# Convert spectrogram to audio using librosa functions

Tags: python, audio, spectrogram, librosa

I am working on speech synthesis and I have constructed spectrograms using librosa. When I want to convert the spectrogram into audio to save as wav file, it creates problem. I looked for help and found that liborsa have a function mel_to_audio but that isn't working.

I used this function to get spectrogram of audio file.

```
librosa.feature.melspectrogram
```

Here is the function I am using to convert spectrogram to audio.

```
librosa.feature.inverse.mel_to_audio
```

But I am getting this error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'librosa.feature.inverse'
```

This is how I am reading file using librosa.

```
def read_audio_from_filename(filename):
    audio, sr = librosa.load(filename)
    D = np.abs(librosa.stft(audio))**2
    audio= librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=audio, sr=sr, S=D)
    return audio
```

Is there any otherway to convert mel to audio and save it as wav file?

Minimal example:

```
import librosa
import librosa.display
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def read_audio_from_filename(filename):
    audio, sr = librosa.load(filename)
    D = np.abs(librosa.stft(audio))**2
    audio= librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=audio, sr=sr, S=D)
    return audio
def convert_data():
    wav_filename = "Audio/Audio1.wav"
    audio = read_audio_from_filename(wav_filename)
    return audio
specto = convert_data()
res = librosa.feature.inverse.mel_to_audio(specto)
```

This is the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'librosa.feature' has no attribute 'inverse'
```

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] along with the complete error message/stack? That would make it much easier to help.

Comment: @hendrik I have added the example

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's definitely not a [mvce]. Line 3 contains a typo `mel)`, `librosa.display_to_audio` does not seem to exist. `DATA_AUDIO_DIR`  is not defined. The imports for `join` and `iglob` are missing. Also, the full error stack is missing.

Comment: please check it now. I just want to generate audio from spectrogram. Using librosa is not mandatory.

Comment: Checked. I'm sorry, but the best I can come up with is my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57970048/942774).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me without error. I recommend reinstalling the latest version of `librosa` using a clean [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) environment:

```
conda install -c conda-forge librosa
```

See also librosa [installation instructions](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/install.html#conda).

Answer (score 1):

The module `librosa.feature.inverse` was introduced in version 0.7. If you install librosa through conda and you don't have the latest version of conda then the version 0.6 will be installed.

A quick fix is installing librosa through pip.